# is it true? $\operatorname{round}(\varphi^{p_n}) \equiv 1 \!\!\pmod{p_n} $ where $p_n$ is $n$th prime number and $\varphi=1.618033...$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

The $\operatorname{round}(\varphi^{n})$ is called n-th Lucas number.
These numbers have most interesting features. One of them is the relationship with prime numbers for example [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.04068)
In this regard, I happened to see that :
$$\operatorname{round}(\varphi^{n})\equiv 1\!\!\!\!\pmod{n}$$
*if and only if $n$ is prime number.*
I wnat to know, is it proven? or it has some exceptions in the larger numbers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $L_n$ be the $n$-th Lucas number. We have $$\text{round}(\varphi^n) = L_n$$ for $n > 2$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_and_Lucas_numbers)). We indeed have

$$L_n \equiv 1 \!\!\pmod n$$

if $n$ is prime ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number#Congruence_relations)), but there are also composite numbers $n$ for which above congruence is true, and these are the [Fibonacci Pseudoprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Fibonacci_pseudoprimes).